# Arranging objects in PowerCenter Designer

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, data-quality, sourceanalyser

I have **two questions**.

1) I am attempting to arrange my objects in the Source Analyzer view into some kind of organized format on display so that i can sort through it. However, the Source analyzer option to "Arrange All" is "greyed" out when i go to the layout control panel. 
Is there any way to arrange or organize the objects?

2) While the objects in my source are organized by the DB i import from, there is no such organized view in navigator for the Targets. All the targets are just dumped into the navigator! Is there any way for me to organize the view of the tables in the Target folder in navigator?

I cannot find answers for these specific questions online, so apologies if they seem basic. Thanks for your help fellow devs!

Answer (score 1):

You can only arrange them manually.

The options `Arrange All` and `Arrange All Iconic` can be used only for mapplets and mappings.

Comment: Great! that's what i thought. Thanks Marek!